# How can I Ignore zero and negative number

Tags: mysql, sql

Where is the mistake in my query

```
SELECT @Total:=SUM(deposit-cost) as Total FROM `vendor_ledger` Where NOT @Total < 0 GROUP BY 
VDR_ID;
```

Anyone Please Help Me

Comment: There doesn't seem to be any point in @total

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to ignore any zero or negative `deposit-cost` amounts in your `sum()` then use a WHERE condition:

```
SELECT SUM(deposit-cost) as Total 
FROM `vendor_ledger` 
WHERE deposit-cost > 0 
GROUP BY VDR_ID;
```

If, instead, you are wanting to ignore any `Total` where it's less than or equal to 0 then use a HAVING condition:

```
SELECT SUM(deposit-cost) as Total 
FROM `vendor_ledger` 
GROUP BY VDR_ID 
HAVING Total > 0;
```